# How do I make sure that files created by docker container are not owned by root

Tags: linux, docker, permissions, docker-compose

​

So, I have read many posts out there talking about this issue, but I've never managed to solve it.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/docker-home-media-server-2018-basic/) to setup a media server.

The problem is that, when I mount a volume to a path that does **not** yet exist on the host machine, the directory and all the files in it are created as root.

I have followed the post-install instructions and did:

`sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`

This is an example of my docker-compose:

```
medusa:
  image: linuxserver/medusa
  container_name: medusa
  environment:
    - PUID=1000
    - PGID=1000
    - TZ=${TZ}
  volumes:
    - /home/myuser-ubuntu/docker/medusa/config:/config
    - /home/myuser-ubuntu/media:/data
ports:
- 8081:8081
restart: unless-stopped
```

Running on Ubuntu Server 18.04, I see this result with the "id" command when I'm logged in as the default user (myuser-ubuntu) created when installing Ubuntu:

`uid=1000(myuser-ubuntu) gid=1000(myuser-ubuntu) groups=1000(myuser-ubuntu),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lxd),1001(docker)`

This user is in the following grups:

`myuser-ubuntu : myuser-ubuntu adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd docker`

The thing is... I **did** manage to run this exact same setup on a Raspberry Pi 3B, running [HypriotOS](https://github.com/hypriot). But the user creation on that O.S. adds the user to a different group. In this case, all the directories and files were created under the myuser-pi user, and myuser-pi group. (Which is what I wanted)

Here are the groups in which "myuser-pi" is:

`myuser-pi : myuser-pi video users docker`

And the output of the "id" command on HypriotOS

`uid=1000(myuser-pi) gid=1000(myuser-pi) groups=1000(myuser-pi),44(video),100(users),999(docker)`

So, I suspect that the fact that myuser-pi does not belong to to the "sudo" group like "myuser-ubuntu" has something to do with the difference in the setups.

Right now, if I create all the directories and sub-directories *before* I start the container, the files that are created in it are not owned by root, but by "myuser-ubuntu" and group "docker".

Any ideas on how I can accomplish the same thing on Ubuntu as I did on HypriotOS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Being no expert in medusa, I see that it allows you to pass the UID and GID you want medusa to use to create the files.
These values can be different for different installations on different OSs (As Raspbian and Ubuntu are different). I would suggest creating a docker compose `.env` file with the GID and UID values for each installation, and define your compose file as

```
medusa:
  image: linuxserver/medusa
  container_name: medusa
  environment:
    - PUID=${UID}
    - PGID=${GID}
    - TZ=${TZ}
  volumes:
    - /home/myuser-ubuntu/docker/medusa/config:/config
    - /home/myuser-ubuntu/media:/data
ports:
- 8081:8081
restart: unless-stopped
```

your env file in raspberry could be

```
UID=1000
GID=1001
```

And you could have different values for your ubuntu installation.

More information on docker compose environment variables here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy, but as the output of the `id` command shows in my original post, I *am* indeed using the correct IDs. I do use the environment variables, just omitted in my question for simplicity. When the folder already exists, the files are created with the right UID and GID. The problem is when the container needs to create folders and sub-folders. Then the folders  are owned by root and so are the files in it.

Comment: @HannonCésar Then you are doing everything right, you should try asking for support in their Github https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-medusa/issues